# how to install numpy for python 2 while I have both py2 and py3 installed

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I'm trying to use python2 version in my pc to run a software, but the error says there is no numpy module (usually I use python3 and the numpy module works well). So I assume that the python2 in my system doesn't have numpy installed. Now my question is that how to install numpy1.10.1 through conda for python2 without affecting python3?

Comment: Do you have python2 in a separate conda environment? If not, it would make it easier if you did, in which case you should read [this](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: Thank you @sacul. May I ask how to know if my two versions are in the same conda environment or not?

Comment: I *believe* it's not possible to have two versions of python in the same conda environment, but I could be wrong. But you could have python2 in outside of an anaconda environment.

Comment: Are you using linux/mac or windows?